# Search results gets cut off by navbar (parent div)

Tags: css

I've been trying to solve this for two straight days and didn't get it right yet.  I basically have a search input inside a nav with results coming from a json file and even though it has a z-index greater than the nav it still gets cut off.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar">
<ul class="navul">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html" style="margin: 0; margin-top: 0;">
        <img src="logo.png" width="40" height="40">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a style="position: relative;" class="active" href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><div class="search-container">
      <form action="" autocomplete="off">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control">
       <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>        <- this is the result box
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the CSS with the navbar, the content which goes under it and the search result box

```
.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px); 
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.navul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
}

.navul a {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  margin: .4em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.12s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 96%;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  position: relative;
}

#result {
   position: absolute;
   width: 40%;
   max-width:870px;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow-y: auto;
   max-height: 400px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 1001;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the minimum CSS required to show the issue?

Comment: @stealththeninja my bad, here it is